# Trouble using json-jackson in camel-blueprint-test

Tags: json, apache-camel, blueprint

I am trying to test a Camel Blueprint route in camel-blueprint-test. This route can load in karaf and it also worked when using Camel and Spring. At this point I am getting:

```
org.apache.camel.FailedToCreateRouteException: Failed to create route route1 at: >>> Unmarshal[ref:IssRequest] <<< in route: Route(route1)[[From[seda:from_rraa]] -> [process[ref:issPrep... because of Data format 'json-jackson' could not be created. Ensure that the data format is valid and the associated Camel component is present on the classpath
    at org.apache.camel.model.RouteDefinition.addRoutes(RouteDefinition.java:1028)
    at org.apache.camel.model.RouteDefinition.addRoutes(RouteDefinition.java:185)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.startRoute(DefaultCamelContext.java:841)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.startRouteDefinitions(DefaultCamelContext.java:2911)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.doStartCamel(DefaultCamelContext.java:2634)
...
```

Other posts have suggested adding camel-jackson in the pom.xml, but I have that already. Also suggested was loading the feature in the karaf container, but this is when running unit tests in camel-blueprint-test, not in real karaf.

Comment: What version of Camel do you use?

Comment: I had the same issue and that was due to pom.xml issue. Can you post the pom where you have included the json-jackson?

Comment: I can't fit the whole pom here, but this is what I have for jackson: 
`  <properties>
    <camel.version>2.15.3</camel.version>
  </properties>    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
      <artifactId>camel-jackson</artifactId>
      <version>${camel.version}</version>
    </dependency>`

Comment: @ClausIbsen - I have Camel 2.15.3

Comment: There is a bug in that version, use 2.15.2 or 2.16.0 or wait for 2.15.4

Comment: @ClausIbsen - thank you! 2.16.0 works.

Comment: Can you mark this as resolved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a bug in that version, use 2.15.2 or 2.16.0 or wait for 2.15.4